# array_pluck with model result Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the index function on my app, that shows a table with all users:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $this->authorize('inet.user.view');
    $users = User::with(['roles', 'groups'])->paginate(10);

    return view('security.users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

But when I try do make the list of groups and roles, i have many errors. This is table:

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="users-table">
    <thead>
        <th>
            @lang('table.generic.name')
        </th>
        <th>
            @lang('table.users.role') & @lang('table.users.group')
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {!! $user->fullname !!}
            </td>
            <td>
                {!! ---HERE NEED TO SHOW LIST OF ROLES--- !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
       @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Im trying to join with `implode(', ', theMethod)` and get the names with [`array_pluck($user, 'roles.name')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-pluck) but doesn't work and [`$user->pluck('roles.name')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) neither.

How can i get the list of roles and groups without doing a `for` in the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate over nested collections loaded with the `with()` method:

```
@foreach($user->roles as $role)
    {{ $role->name }}
@endforeach

@foreach($user->groups as $group)
    {{ $group->name }}
@endforeach
```

If you want to use `implode()`, use `pluck()` to get names:

```
implode(', ', $user->roles->pluck('name')->toArray())
```

Comment: perfect, that's what I wanted to do. But I just discovered that a collection has implode method too .. `$user->roles->implode('name', ', ')` https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-implode